# Rails custom ActionView::Base.field_error_proc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

after changing the `field_error_proc` routine, to customizing error css in rails views, I realize that if there is only one field with error, and this field is marked to be hidden, this method is not called.

Here is my customization:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance_tag|
  "<span class='field_error'>#{html_tag}</span>".html_safe
end
```

If I change the `f.hidden_field` to a `f.text_field`, the method is called..

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: why would you mark a hidden field?!

Comment: Hi phoet, this field is hidden only to hold the id of a field (my order question). The name field is displayed in an autocomplete field. So, the text in the visible autocomplete, and the id in the hidden one. The problem is that this hidden field, even with post errors, does not trigger the field_error_proc method.